# I'm not able to start the mongo db server, getting the following error: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

This is server.js and .env file
I'm trying to start the server but it is throwing an error.

**server.js**

```
 const express = require('express');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 require('dotenv').config();

 const app = express();
 const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

 app.use(cors());
 app.use(express.json());

 const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
 mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });

 const connection = mongoose.connection;
 connection.once('open',() => {
     console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
 })
 app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
 })
```

**.env**

```
ATLAS_URI = mongodb+srv://rnvsri:vastav123@cluster0.dgnw1.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**Issue:**

In cmd, I'm giving the command **nodemon server.js**

but the server is not starting and it is throwing the following error.

```
nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1334:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1382:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1469:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/rnvsrivastava/mern/restaurant-reviews/backend/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rnvsrivastava/mern/restaurant-reviews/backend/backend/server.js:20:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1361:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can someone help?

Comment: your port (5000) is already in use. change the port to something else or kill the port

Answer (score 0):

port you are using is used by another process you can find it by
command
`lsof -i :PORT`  and can kill using kill command

`kill PID`